# Add rating and remove onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
         <div id="rating" class="ratings no-padding">
             <div class="star_1 ratings_stars"></div>
             <div class="star_2 ratings_stars"></div>
             <div class="star_3 ratings_stars"></div>
             <div class="star_4 ratings_stars"></div>
             <div class="star_5 ratings_stars"></div>
             <div class="star_6 ratings_stars"></div>
             <div class="star_7 ratings_stars"></div>
             <div class="star_8 ratings_stars"></div>
             <div class="star_9 ratings_stars"></div>
             <div class="star_10 ratings_stars"></div>
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>

$('.ratings_stars').hover(

            // Handles the mouseover

            function () {

                $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');


            },

            // Handles the mouseout

            function () {

                $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');

            }

        );
```

Here is my code.. The problem is I need the code to work for onClick, not hover. I'm trying to change the rating stars on click. For hover works fine, but it's not what I need. What can I do? Any ideas?

Comment: So what did you try? What is failing? Seems like you want the first part inside the onclick

Comment: I've tryied to change the hover with click..but not working

Comment: Well click only has one function

Comment: search for `toggleClass` on the jQuery docs

Comment: The `on` function should help: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: http://codepen.io/edisonpappi/pen/oBQNvy bro take a look on this

Comment: Yes, well, it can be `on` to `toggleClass` or anything else. The basic fact is that all the OP say is that they tried something that doesn't work. What i'm going to try is to close this question as "Why isn't this code working?"

Comment: @AlonEitan I've provided a sample solution. Maybe it's a good hint to understand this kind of topic.

Comment: @Ema.jar Well I believe it's the best one can do with the details (Or lack of them) provided by the OP, yes, i'll upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can use the on() function described [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

The code will become something like that:

```
$('.ratings_stars').on('click',
            function () {
                $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
            }
        );
```

I've created a code pen that can help you: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeZqmY

Comment: it's what I need.. the problem is when I'm clicking outside the numbers..the class is removed..and I don't want that...

Comment: @driveaferrari edit your question and describe the expected behaviour. Please provide some example so I can edit the codepen ;-)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bgpzyayh/ Here is the code... I have no idea why but on jsfiddle not works...what I need is to make change stars...it's a rating system.